# JBoss Session Automatically Expire After 30 second

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

JBoss session automatically expire after 30 second...

Can you tell me, what is the process to extend JBoss session time limit?

Comment: Refer to : https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HttpSessionTimeout
The HttpSession timeout in JBoss can be set at three different levels:
web.xml
<session-config> <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> </session-config> Your message doesn't really give much more information :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jboss, session timeout can be increased in two ways,
Either for all applications by specifying it in

> jboss's web.xml

or application specific by specifying it in

> application's web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

jboss's web.xml location will be different depending on jboss version.

in jboss4 it is

> jboss/server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/conf/web.xml

in jboss5 it is

> deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml

No idea about later version's

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(int secs);
```

and in case your require a full detail, visit the link :
    http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2014/01/15/changing-default-session-timeout-jboss-7/